# Truncated normal with a given mean

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, probability, distribution

Is it possible in python to generate a truncated normal distribution with a given expected value? I know that scipy.stats.truncnorm can give a truncated normal distribution that takes the mean of the *original* normal distribution as a parameter, but I want to create a truncated normal distribution such that the expected value of the truncated distribution is a particular value. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

You could convert between `mu` and mean, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution for details,
for mean there is simple expression, to get `mu` you have to solve nonlinear equation

```
import scipy
from scipy.stats import norm

def get_mean(mu, sigma, a, b):
    alpha = (a - mu)/sigma
    beta  = (b - mu)/sigma
    Z     = norm.cdf(beta) - norm.cdf(alpha)
    return mu + (norm.pdf(alpha) - norm.pdf(beta)) / Z

def f(x, mean, sigma, a, b):
    return mean - get_mean(x, sigma, a, b)

def get_mu(mean, sigma, a, b):
    mu = scipy.optimize.brentq(f, a, b, args=(mean, sigma, a, b))
    return mu

a  = -2.0
b  = 3.0
sigma = 1.0
mu    = 0.0

mean = get_mean(mu, sigma, a, b)
print(mean)

mu = get_mu(mean, sigma, a, b)
print(mu)
```

After getting `mu` from desired mean, you could put it into sampling routine

Comment: The wiki page you are pointing to in your response gives the mean as mu+(pdf(alpha)-pdf(beta))*(1/Z)*sigma. So if I compare this to your get_mean function, it seems to me like you are lacking a *sigma.