# Generate n random values from a specific mean and range values

Tags: python, r, statistics

I want to generate 100 random values from a specific mean and specific range values.
Do you know a function that do that in R or Python ?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Does this post help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49855569/how-to-generate-random-numbers-to-satisfy-a-specific-mean-and-median-in-python ?

Comment: This is not enough information. Can the mean be any value between the minimum and maximum or is it in the middle of the range? Are you assuming a particular distribution such as uniform, random, Poisson, negative binomial, or a custom distribution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that R solution could meet your expectations

first (if needed) use `install.packages("truncnorm")` to install package

then

```
library(truncnorm)
rtruncnorm(n=100, a=0, b= 10, mean=5, sd=5)
```

Comment: Since they are asking for both R and python, it might be useful to say that this is in R. Also, they will have to `install.packages("truncnorm")` first. I'm not sure how familiar they are with the languages.

Comment: you are absolutely right

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, this is what I look for exactly

Answer (score 1):

This depends on what distribution you want your random values to come from. Another option would be a uniform distribution. In R you could do

```
n <- 100
mu <- 10
myrange <- 10
runif(n, mu - myrange/2, mu + myrange/2)
```

to get 100 draws from a uniform around the mean 10.